# What is wrong with this Dart error handler?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm doing some (I thought) basic exception handling in dart / flutter.  I'm using the latest versions of dart and flutter as of last week (3/15/2019).

Here's my code:

```
void MyMethod() {
    Storage.getFilePaths().then((paths) {
      //do something
    }).catchError((Exception error) {
      //do something else
      return null;
    });
 }
```

However, when running the program and when an exception occurs I get this message below and can't see what the problem is?

> 'Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or
>   one Object and a StackTrace as  arguments, and return a a valid
>   result: Closure: (Exception) => Null'

I assume I'm missing something silly, and would love to learn what that is.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
}).catchError((Exception error) {
```

has to be

```
}).catchError((Object error) {
```

You can't limit to `Exception` here. Dart can throw all kinds of values.

Comment: how do I get the actual error then? I need to access fields of the thrown error.

Comment: You might need to cast like `}).catchError((Object error) { if(error is MyError) print((error as MyError).someField; }` but difficult to tell without more details. Perhaps it's worth a new question with a full but minimal reproduction.

Comment: Also consider using `async`/`await` with `try`/`catch` instead of `catchError`. `catchError` can be quite tricky to get right.

Comment: If I do not provide the type of the error (`Object`) Dart does not complain but fails during execution if the `err` has not the expected field (makes sense). I will try your suggested approach as soon I am back at my place.